# Making simple client/proxy/server programs using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, client, server

I'm working on an assignment where I have to make 3 programs, a client, a proxy, and a server. The client is supposed to send messages to the server by sending them to the proxy, which sends them to the server, and vice versa. The server waits for the proxy to connect to it, and the proxy waits for the client to connect to it, then the client sends a message to the proxy which gets sent to the server. When I compile them though, while the proxy gets the message fine, the serve gets an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at Server.run(Server.java:18)
at Server.main(Server.java:8)
```

Here is the client code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Client serv = new Client();
    serv.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception{
    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    ps.println("Hello Server");
    sock.close();
    }

}
```

Here is the proxy,

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Proxy {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
    Proxy serv = new Proxy();
    serv.run();
}

    public void run() throws Exception{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);
    Socket sock = ss.accept();

    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

    String message = "";
    message = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(message);

    Socket sck = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

    boolean waiting = true;
    while(waiting){
        if(message != null){
        ps.println("Hey Server, Client says: " + message);
        waiting = false;
        }
    }
    sock.close();
    }

}
```

and here is the server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
    Server serv = new Server();
    serv.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
    Socket sock = ss.accept();

    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    sock.close();
    ss.close();
    }

}
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your loop is wrong.  It doesn't act as a loop.  You simply need to read from the socket in the loop.  You shouldn't exit the loop until you read a null line from the stream.  What error are you getting?

Comment: try call `ps.flush();` after `ps.println()` in `Proxy.run()`

Comment: You're doing everything wrong. Your proxy server is single-threaded; it uses Readers and Writers where it should use streams; it copies exactly one line from client to server, and nothing in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your proxy. First the `sock` Socket represents the connection with the client, then the `sck` Socket represents the connection with the server. However, when you create your PrintStream `ps` to connect with the server, you are using `sock.getOutputStream` as opposed to `sck.getOutputStream`. You are telling it to send information *back* to the client, which does not have an open BufferedReader to interpret, nor an open Socket at that point. Attempting to write to a closed connection results in a connection reset exception.

Secondly (though this is not causing the error), your proxy while loop is all jacked up. If you examine it, it will obviously cycle through at *least* once because waiting is defaulted to true. Then, you are checking to see if `message != null`. In this case, `message` will never be null because the client is set to always send the same message, and only one message. Most importantly, however, if for whatever reason `message` *was* null, there is nothing in the while loop to change that -- it does not attempt to read the next value from `br` or anything, so you will simply be stuck in an infinite while loop.

I believe what you were looking for was this:

```
String message;
while((message = br.readLine()) != null){
    ps.println("Hey server, Client says: " + message);
}
```

But as I said, a while loop is not necessary in this case because the client is set to send only one message anyways, so you can simply do this:

```
ps.println("Hey server, Client says: " + message);
```

... without any sort of looping.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks, I got rid of the while loop and corrected sock to sck, and the server got the message, thank you!